# SQLLite Getting record count from Join table

Tags: sql, sqlite, left-join

I have two tables I have Join together which returns 99 records.

Instead of getting 99 records I need just the count. I have two query I have tried after doing  some searching but both are still retuning 99 records. So I have something wrong.

The lotw table will have or could have multiples record  for one country representative by a country code (field: dxcc).
The country table holds the country with it's associated country code (field: code).

What I would like is the numbers of unique counties that are associated with the band 20M. in the lotw table.

first I tried

```
SELECT COUNT(cc.code)
FROM lotw l
JOIN CountryCode AS cc on cc.code = l.dxcc 
WHERE l.DXCC > '' AND l.BAND IN ('20M')
GROUP BY l.DXCC
```

Then I tried

```
SELECT COUNT(cc.total)
FROM lotw l
JOIN (SELECT code,COUNT(Country) As total FROM CountryCode GROUP BY code) AS cc on cc.code = l.dxcc 
WHERE l.DXCC > '' AND l.BAND IN ('20M')
GROUP BY l.DXCC
```

I prefer the second method if I can get that to work because, I have to join a couple more tables later on

Answer (score 0):

Just remove from query

```
GROUP BY l.DXCC
```

Comment: Hello VitaliyG, Thanks for the reply, I remove l.dxcc and I get the count but its incorrect the countrycode.code is showing duplicates? I need to have have the Countries unique? So I tried "SELECT code,COUNT(DISTINCT Country)" but I get the same results of 662. hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I needed to reverse my query so this worked.

```
SELECT COUNT(l.total)
FROM CountryCode cc
JOIN (SELECT dxcc, COUNT(*) As total FROM lotw  WHERE DXCC > '' AND BAND IN ('20M') GROUP BY dxcc) AS l on l.dxcc = cc.code
```